# Get list of Workspace which are already checked in

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I am using TFS 2012. So after I checkin a changes of a workspace to the server I don’t need that workspace any more in my server. So how it can be deleted logically? The entries from the database need to be deleted for that workspace?

How can I get the list of workspace whose changes are already checked in ? I think there will be sql some script by using database and tables of that collection. I tried to identify from workspace table entries. But didn’t find any identification there. So please help.

Answer (score 0):

This little program should work for you:

```
class Program
{
    static private TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("myuri"));

        var service = _tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
        Workspace[] ws = service.QueryWorkspaces(null, null, null);

        foreach(Workspace s in ws)
        {
            var pend = s.GetPendingChanges();
            if (pend.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Workspace {0} has no pending changes", s.Name);
                // s.Delete()
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I believe that uncommenting the Delete will clear them for you, but that is untested, so use with caution.